# Why is my Failing on my Unity Android Build?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build

I am using unity 2020 1.1f1. I get an error while converting the project to apk. I put the errors below. I would appreciate it if you help. Thank you.

```
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

* What went wrong:

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Execution failed for task ':launcher:lintVitalRelease'.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':launcher:lintClassPath'.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

   > Could not download intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.6.0)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.6.0/intellij-core-26.6.0.jar'.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.6.0/intellij-core-26.6.0.jar'.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

            > dl.google.com

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

   > Could not download kotlin-compiler.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:kotlin-compiler:26.6.0)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

      > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.6.0/kotlin-compiler-26.6.0.jar'.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

         > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/kotlin-compiler/26.6.0/kotlin-compiler-26.6.0.jar'.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

* Try:

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

BUİLD FAILED in 1s

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Configure project :launcher

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

WARNING: The option 'android.enableR8' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

It will be removed in a future version of the Android Gradle plugin, and will no longer allow you to disable R8.

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\build-tools\28.0.3\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platform-tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\platforms\android-28\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

Exception while marshalling C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2020.1.1f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\tools\package.xml. Probably the SDK is read-only

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:preBuild UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:compileReleaseAidl NO-SOURCE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:parseReleaseLocalResources UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:desugarReleaseFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:extractDeepLinksRelease UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:mergeExtDexRelease UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:validateSigningRelease UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:packageReleaseAssets

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibResRelease UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:mergeReleaseNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:stripReleaseDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:copyReleaseJniLibsProjectOnly UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:processReleaseManifest

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:generateReleaseRFile UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:mergeReleaseAssets

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :unityLibrary:bundleLibRuntimeRelease UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:processReleaseManifest

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:processReleaseResources

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:compileReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

> Task :launcher:lintVitalRelease FAILED

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

41 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 35 up-to-date
```

Comment: Did you install Android SDK using Unity Hub, or do you have your own external install?

Comment: `Could not download` looks like something is blocking your connection. Did you add firewall exception for JDK when it was asking on first build?

Comment: I did not install android sdk using unity hub, but I downloaded it using the link in modules.json file, I threw it there.

Comment: I don't remember I gave my permission I had to erase some of the error half of this error

Comment: I turned off the firewall and it worked after trying 5 times.Thank you very much!